# Continuous functions and vertical and horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus

How many vertical asymptotes can a continuous function have? and how many horizontal asymptotes can a continuous functions have?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Do you know when the two types of asymptotes exist?

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange! Can you provide more background on this question? Where are you stuck, what have you tried, etc.?

Comment: Is some domain for the function specified?

Comment: This is a general question.  For a given interval, the maximum numbers of horizontal asymptotes, I think can be two, where teh continuous interval will be bounded by the horizontal asymptotes.  Since sometimes we cross the horizontal asymptotes so the end points of the interval will be included.